# Ionic 3 - home button with a slide

Tags: ionic3

I am a beginner in ionic 3.
I wanted to make the moste simple page without any header and nav-bar component.
( Especially because I want to have a unique background image on the full app)

Since I created a  slider on my page, the Home doesn't work anymore.

What would be the easiest way to fix it?

cuba.html :

```
    <ion-content class="main_backgroundBlack">

  <div id="Table_01">


      <div id="Page-detail-cigare-03">
          CASAHORACIO BY CASANUEVA CIGARS
        </div>
        <div id="Page-detail-cigare-04">
            <a href="#" (click)="OpenHome()">Home</a> > Cuban cigars
        </div>



    <ion-slides>


      <ion-slide>

          <div id="Page-detail-cigare-07">
              BOLIVARS
            </div>
          <div id="Page-detail-cigare-09">
            BELICOSOS FINOS
          </div>
          <div id="prix">
            CHF 17.90-
          </div>

          <div id="Page-detail-cigare-11">
              - MODULE : BELICOSO <br>
              - RING : 52 <br>
              - INTENSITÉ : FORT <br>
              - ARÔME : TERREUX <br>
          </div>

          <div id="photo-cigar">
            <img src="assets/imgs/cigars/Belicos_finos.png" />
          </div>

          <div id="Page-detail-cigare-14">
              Un cigare très agréable et régulier en tirage. Démarrage agréable sur des notes douces et légères qui restent constantes avec un parfum boisé et un goût épicé. Un Belicoso idéal pour une fin d'après-midi. Son format est un parfait complément au Robusto. 
          </div>

  </ion-slide>










  <ion-slide>
      <div id="Page-detail-cigare-09">
          BELICOS FINOS
        </div>

        <div id="Page-detail-cigare-11">
          TEMPS DE DEGUSTATION : 15mn <br>
          AROME: Boisé <br>
          MODULE : Gran Panatela
        </div>

        <div id="Page-detail-cigare-14">
          CIGAR DESCRIPTION
        </div>
    </ion-slide>

  </ion-slides>



  </div>

  </ion-content>
```

Cuba.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import{ HomePage } from '../home/home';

/**
 * Generated class for the CubaPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cuba',
  templateUrl: 'cuba.html',
})
export class CubaPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CubaPage');
  }

  OpenHome(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }


}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards,

Pierre

Comment: what exact error do you get?

Comment: Hello I don't get any error.. I have some warnings in debug console but mot related.. The link just doesn't work when I put " <ion-slides>" tag and works when I remove it..